# Multiple load balancer using mod_proxy_balancer on httpd

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-proxy-balancer

Understand that to use `mod_proxy_balancer` on httpd via `ajp`, configuration is as follow:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
      BalancerMember ajp://public1.yourcompany.com:8009 route=public1
      BalancerMember ajp://public2.yourcompany.com:8009 route=public2
      ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

However in my case, i need to have 2 clusters, so i'm thinking to create 2 Proxies like this:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
  BalancerMember ajp://public1.yourcompany.com:8009 route=public1
  BalancerMember ajp://public2.yourcompany.com:8009 route=public2
  ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
<Proxy balancer://my2ndcluster>
  BalancerMember ajp://public3.yourcompany.com:8009 route=public1
  BalancerMember ajp://public4.yourcompany.com:8009 route=public2
  ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

However with this httpd failed to start.

Anyway for me to configure this?

Thank you

Comment: akf there is nothing in that chunk of configuration that would make it fail to start, so please, to make 100% sure, share the error entry you get in error.log when it fails to start. In any case you should fix "route" parameter since obviously in second cluster it should be route=3 and route=4

Comment: @ezra-s Thanks...found that it is not the configuration that is causing the issue. Works well after fixing and changed the route id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue that is not related to the proxy settings. After fixing the problem and changing the route ID as suggested, the proxy worked as expected.